# Chrome picture in picture extension with options similar to Opera's in-built feature

Tags: gratis, chrome, video-player, browser-extension

Is there any "picture in picture" Chrome extension that has these features:

- player with options like volume controls and timeline
- option for the videos to go automatically into this mode whenever you switch tabs/application, preferably changeable in icon menu, but settings are fine too

?

I tested few of the most popular ones with 100+ ratings, e.g. [Floating Video with Playback Controls](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/floating-video-with-playb/pnanegnllonoiklmmlegcaajoicfifcm), but none of them met the 2nd criteria, you have to click an icon for the popup to appear. Not even sure if the APi allows such a functionality to exist.

I would like for it to be free and it should work with all kinds of video sites.